# Stealing two-finger pan from mkmapview

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, gestures

I've placed a UIview above an MKMapView with the intention of stealing the two-finger pan from the map view when I am tracking a user's location. If you notice Google maps app does this on the phone as well.

But I'm at a loss as to how to do it. I want to be able to enable it and disable it at will depending on whether the location is being tracked or not. All other gestures and touches should be passed onto the mapview

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're going for OS 4 and above, the easy way is NOT to use a UIView, but instead to add a gesture-recognizer directly onto the mapview, e.g.:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer* gest = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
[mapView addGestureRecognizer:gest];
```

...and then all swipe gestures (in that case) would get passed to [self handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*) x];

If you look in the docs around gesture recognizers, there's a wide variety of options, and you can add them to a pretty fine-level of granularity (tap vs swipe, how many fingers used, etc)

Comment: There is a single finger and two finger pan. How do I pass the single finger gesture back to the mapview?

Comment: I've tried this but the selector is not being called


`UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(twoFingerPanGesture:)];
pan.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2; 
pan.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2; [map addGestureRecognizer:pan]; 
[pan release];`

Comment: You might not be safe to release it?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I can't remember if addGestureRecognizer retains or not. Also, I'd try this first with a plain UIView in a new blank project (not Map), just in case there's something unusual about Map, or something unusual in your viewcontroller that's confusing the issue

Comment: ok, I'll have a look at it again later. It's not a priority as you can imagine but I'd like to improve the user experience and panning while tracking your location is not good in my opinion and is just annoying.